# input text(number), checkbox value(text) output result

Tags: javascript

I need output result with input number and checkbox value(text).

I made some code.

It's compare with prepared data, and display result, but only use number is too large range.

so I changed checkbox value 'a,b,c' instead of '1,2,3', but it's not working.

how can I fix this?

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload=function(){
$('.height,.style').on('change, input', 
function(){
$('.total').val($('.height').val() * $('.style:checked').val());
});
$('.height,.style').on('change, input', 
function(){
    var total2 = $( 'input#total' ).val();
    if ( total2 == 168a ) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'S';
    } else if ( total2 == 170a) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'M';
    } else if ( total2 == 182a) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';
    } else if ( total2 == 165b) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'S';
    } else if ( total2 == 175b) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'M';
    } else if ( total2 == 180b) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'L';
    } else if ( total2 == 175c) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'L';
    } else if ( total2 == 176c) {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';

    } else {
        document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';
    }
});
function onlyNumber(){
    if((event.keyCode<48)||(event.keyCode>57))
        event.returnValue=false;
    }
}
</script>

<table>
<tbody>        
<tr id="person_total">
<td><input name="height" type="number" class="span1 height" min="150" max="200" maxlength="3"></td>
<td>
<input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="a">
<label for="kjc-small">S</label>
<input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="b" checked="">
<label for="kjc-normal">N</label>
<input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="c">
<label for="kjc-big">B</label>
</td>

<td><input name="total" type="hidden" id="total" class="span1 total"></td>

</tr>
</tbody>
</table>

<div id="total2"></div>
```

Comment: What is 168a, 165b and etc? Is it a typo of quote?

Comment: it's a size. height 165~190cm, style 'small normal big'
we have prepared size table, and just display compare result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, * is not for string concatenation. + is for concatenation... so some number + '(null)' + some letter will return a string. In your if statements, you need them to read as strings... so "170a", instead of 170a. The computer doesn't recognize what 170a is... is it a integer, a float, etc.? Versus "170a" is obviously a string, which computers can check to see if strings are equal to one another, i.e. `var x = 'hi'; if (x == 'hi') { alert('yes!'); }`. You don't have to make another event listener, listening for the same events, rather just call another function, or even include the code inside the function of the listener to run the code.

So this will do what your almost javascript / jQuery / psuedocode describes... however... if you want it to do what I think you intend for it to do... give me like 15 mins. Edit: Scratch that. I don't have enough data to determine what needs to go where... The concept is there... and it works in terms of returning the information.

```js
        window.onload=function()
        {
            $('.height,.style').on('change, input', 
                function(){
                    var my_var = $(".height").val() + '' + $("input[name='stylebox']:checked").val();
                    //alert(my_var);
                    document.getElementById('total').value = my_var;
                    update_func(my_var);
            });
            //No need to have that twice...
            /*$('.height,.style').on('change, input', */

            function update_func(x){
            //this is x
                total2 = x;
                /*var total2 = $( 'input#total' ).val();*/
                if ( total2 == '168a') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'S';
                } else if ( total2 == '170a') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'M';
                } else if ( total2 == '182a') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';
                } else if ( total2 == '165b') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'S';
                } else if ( total2 == '175b') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'M';
                } else if ( total2 == '180b') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'L';
                } else if ( total2 == '175c') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'L';
                } else if ( total2 == '176c') {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';
                } else {
                    document.getElementById("total2").innerHTML = 'XL';
                }
            }

            function onlyNumber()
            {
                if((event.keyCode<48)||(event.keyCode>57))
                {
                    event.returnValue=false;
                }
            }
        }
```

```html
    <html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="person_total">
            <td><input id="height" name="height" type="number" class="span1 height" min="150" max="200" maxlength="3"></td>
            <td>
                <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="a">
                <label for="kjc-small">S</label>
                <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="b" checked="">
                <label for="kjc-normal">N</label>
                <input type="radio" name="stylebox" class="style" value="c">
                <label for="kjc-big">B</label>
            </td>
            <td><input name="total" type="hidden" id="total" class="span1 total"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>

    <div id="total2"></div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: 'Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier' occurred in line 6
I'm a newbie, so i don't know how to fix this..

Comment: Look at it again... I just updated it. Comment if you have any further questions.